# addind coin values in python- cannot get total to sum up

Tags: python-3.x

i am taking a beginner computer programming course and we have a lab for couting coins.  i am unable to get the coins to output the total dollar and cents and i have spent so long looking at the code and for examples online to see what i am missing.  Can anyone help: here is my code so far, and the lab is below.

```
print("Please enter the number of coins:")

quarters=int(input("# of quarters:"))

quarters=quarters*25

dimes=int(input("# of dimes:"))

dimes=dimes*10

nickels=int(input("# of nickels:"))

nickels=nickels*5

pennies=int(input("# of pennies:"))

pennies=pennies*1

dollars_cents=quarters+dimes+nickels+pennies

print("The total is"),dollars,("dollars and"),cents,("cents")

dollars=dollars_cents//100
cents=dollars_cents%100

output:

Please enter the number of coins:
# of quarters:20
# of dimes:4
# of nickels:13
# of pennies:17
The total is
```

Write a program that asks the user to enter a number of quarters, dimes, nickels and pennies
and then outputs the monetary value of the coins in the format of dollars and remaining cents.
Your program should interact with the user exactly as it shows in the following example:

```
Please enter the number of coins:
# of quarters: 20
# of dimes: 4
# of nickels: 13
# of pennies: 17
The total is 6 dollars and 22 cents
```

Comment: The print statement in the last line is incorrectly defined. Please check the brackets

Comment: It should be `print("The total is" ,dollars, "dollars and" ,cents, "cents")

Comment: And the print statement should be after you calculate the dollars and cents. Not before you calculate

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/843953 Your question does not contain any error message or does not show any work you have done to find the cause of the error yourself. http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ Please take the [tour], read [ask] and [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: thank you!! i was moving the print statement around to try and get it to work, just trying anything at this point.  Once i fixed the brackets it worked! thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change your print statement. Otherwise, good work:

```
print(f'The total is {dollars_cents//100} dollars and {dollars_cents% 100} cents')
```

if you are using Python 2 and can not use f' statements, just move your print statement to the last line of your code.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments your print statement is missing a closing bracket i.e., `)`, however, I think it you may also want to consider adding some input validation so that if the user does not enter a valid integer your program does not break:

```
DOLLARS_TO_CENTS = 100
QUARTERS_TO_CENTS = 25
DIMES_TO_CENTS = 10
NICKELS_TO_CENTS = 5
PENNIES_TO_CENTS = 1

def get_int_input(prompt: str) -> int:
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            print("Error: Enter an integer, try again...")

def main():
    print("Please enter the number of coins:")
    num_quarters = get_int_input("# of quarters: ")
    num_dimes = get_int_input("# of dimes: ")
    num_nickels = get_int_input("# of nickels: ")
    num_pennies = get_int_input("# of pennies: ")
    total_in_cents = num_quarters * QUARTERS_TO_CENTS + \
                     num_dimes * DIMES_TO_CENTS + \
                     num_nickels * NICKELS_TO_CENTS + \
                     num_pennies * PENNIES_TO_CENTS
    num_dollars = total_in_cents // DOLLARS_TO_CENTS
    num_cents = total_in_cents % DOLLARS_TO_CENTS
    print(f"The total is {num_dollars} dollars and {num_cents} cents")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Example Usage:**

```
Please enter the number of coins:
# of quarters: a
Error: Enter an integer, try again...
# of quarters: 20
# of dimes: 4
# of nickels: 13
# of pennies: 17
The total is 6 dollars and 22 cents
```